# Reload Data in DataGridView vs2015 c#

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a new application . I am using a dataGridView. there is a child form that inserts data into the database. and there is a gridview docked to the Parent MDI form. i need a way of reloading the data into the gridview after i insert data or delete. 
ive searched everywhere but there are no satisactory answers.
i tried `DataGridView1.Databind()` but this is not a supported method apparently

help will be much appreciated

Comment: DataGridView.datasource =

Comment: @alex Krupa can you please clarify

Comment: @AlexKrupka can you please clarify.  The datagridview was not data  bounded using code.  I used properties in visual Studio